# I found the matrices but can't find the inverse kinematics angles

Tags: kinematics

I need to find inverse and forward kinematics of Mitsubishi RV-M2 as a homewrok. I found the forward kinematics part. But I got stuck in inverse kinematics.

Teacher said we can think that wrist joints is not moving.(To make equations easier I guess.) This is why I thought tetha4(in T4) and tetha5(in T5) should be 0.

Here is my MATLABcode

```
syms t1 t2 t3 d1 a1 a2 a3 d5 px py pz r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 % sybolic equations

T1=[cos(t1)     -sin(t1)        0       0;
    sin(t1)     cos(t1)         0       0;
    0            0              1       d1;
    0            0              0       1;];

T2=[cos(t2)     -sin(t2)        0       a1; 
    0            0              -1      0; 
    sin(t2)     cos(t2)         0       0;
    0            0              0       1;];

T3=[cos(t3)     -sin(t3)        0       a2;
    sin(t3)     cos(t3)         0       0;
    0             0             1       0;
    0             0             0       1;];

T4= [0           -1             0       a3;   
     1             0             0       0;
     0             0             1       0;
     0             0             0       1;];

T5=[1             0             0       0; 
    0             0            -1      -d5; 
    0             1             0       0;
    0             0             0       1;];

Tg= [r1 r2 r3 px;
    r4 r5 r6 py;
    r7 r8 r9 pz;
    0 0 0 1;];

left= inv(T1)* Tg;
left=left(1:4,4);
left=simplify(left)
right= T2*T3*T4*T5;
right=right(1:4,4);
right=simplify(right)
```

This gives us
[image: matrice]

I find t1 using this and results are matching with forward kinematics equations.  But I couldn't find t2 and t3. How can  I do that? Is there a formula or somethig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to just give the answer....try squaring the $x$ and $z$ terms (after moving $a_1$ to the left) and see where that gets you.